# Declare array of UIButtons

Tags: arrays, swift, button, var, declare

I want my swift code to create buttons using colors. I know I want to declare array but some of the things I have tried are not working. What I tried below is not working. I have tried to do various forms of wrapping but it did not work. The goal of this code is to not use any storyboards and do everything by code.

```
  var red,blue = UIButton()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What exactly do you expect to happen?

Comment: I am getting a error Type annotation missing in pattern

Comment: "What I tried below is not working"  That's because there are rules in declaring a variable, and you don't abide by them.

Comment: An array declaration looks like this `var buttons = [UIButton]()`. You are declaring two variables `red` and `blue`, one of which has no type. Anyway, what do you want to do with the array? Closing as unclear.

Comment: Could you add more code and explain more clearly. I'm not sure what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One compact way to declare two variables in one line is to use tuple notation:

```
let (red,blue) = (UIButton(), UIButton())
```

Perhaps that's what you're asking for. But there is no *array* in the story; it's hard to see why you mention arrays in the first place.

On the other hand, if you really do want an *array* as you claim, then it's hard to see what the names `red` and `blue` are for, since the elements of an array do not have names (with regard to the array). You could make an array of two new buttons by saying:

```
let arrayOfTwoButtons = (0..<2).map {_ in UIButton()}
```